# Limit SQL Server log file growth rate

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a big database of 2.3 billion rows and size of 76gb.

My problem is that I want to convert a column type to `smalldatetime` but during this operation the .ldf file grows so big that it takes my entire disk space (it got up to 350gb) and then query exits with error.

Is there any way to keep the .ldf small?

I shrinked my .ldf from options.

Database recovery model is set to simple.

Comment: Could [THIS](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31838/how-to-disable-ldf-file-or-limit-its-size) be helpful to you?  (Point 2, Set Auto Shrink to True)

Comment: @Ricardo No, please do not turn on auto shrink!

Comment: Do NOT enable auto shrink; that will wreak havoc to your database. Also, it does not affect the LDF file in this regard, as it's a single transaction growing it.

Comment: Turn auto-grow off will do no good either?

Comment: @Ricardo No, that will be even worse. Have you ever tried any of these things you're suggesting?

Comment: I read [this](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files/) and he looks so convinced that Shrinking the log is necessary if your log has grown out of control, and looks like he knows what he is doing.

Comment: @Ricardo you shrink a log file when there has been an abnormal event (such as this). This is something you do *once*. There is absolutely no reason to turn on the auto-shrink feature, or to turn off auto-grow (this just means the query will die sooner).

Comment: Yes, but in this case Agis doesn't need to shrink the log, he needs to keep it from growing in the first place.

Comment: Right, and that does not mean turning off auto-grow, it means performing the operation in a way that doesn't create such a high volume of log activity.

Comment: Either de maximum size attribute will help then?

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña It will not, that will just cause the query to fail sooner rather than later as it's then artificially limited in size.

Comment: The log in SQL Server is not optional. It is not like a web-server text log that you can just throw away. It is essential so you can't turn it off or limit it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your replies , I already tried the maximum size and i got error.

Answer (score 3):

Add a new nullable column of type smalldatetime. Then slowly (that is, batches of 10-100k rows, for instance) populate that column by setting its value based on the old columns value. Once all rows have a value in the new column, drop the old one and rename the new one to the old ones name.

That'll ensure no transaction becomes big enough to severely impact your log file.

Answer (score 0):

here is the final code : 
I run it now so I will know if its 100%  good tommorow , but it seems to work

```
 WHILE (2 > 1) 
  BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    UPDATE TOP ( 10000 ) [ais].[dbo].[imis position report]
    SET    [time2] = convert(smalldatetime, left(date, 19)) 
     IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
      BEGIN 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
         BREAK 
      END 
    COMMIT TRANSACTION 
    -- 1 second delay
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
  END -- WHILE
GO
```

Comment: The code above doesnt work :( It still fill the log file and drop an error

Comment: What is the `log_reuse_wait_desc` value in sys.databases while the script runs? (Please check after a few minutes). Try inserting `CHECKPOINT` after every `COMMIT`.

Comment: You'll be able to find that out yourself by searching for the identifiers that I mentioned.

Comment: Also note that you'll need a `WHERE [time2] IS NULL` predicate on your update statement, otherwise it'll just update the same rows over and over, never finishing the job. Even so, it shouldn't fill up the log as you're batching it correctly.